# Can I specify which Columns are editable in a WPF DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, editing

I have a WPF 4.0 DataGrid with AutoGenerated columns. I would like to only allow the user to edit the first column. Is there an easy way of doing this?

I was trying to add a DataGridCell style and set it's editing ability based on either ColumnName (1st column always has the same name) or ColumnIndex, however I cannot figure out the correct XAML for this, or even if it is possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got it.... here's what I used:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Value="PART_IsSelected" Binding="{Binding Path=Column.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

If you want, you can use `Column.DisplayIndex` instead of Column.Header

I'm still not sure why the binding won't work directly and needs to be referenced by a RelativeSource, but at least it works :)

Answer (score 20):

The below sample does the trick for one or more columns

```
  private void Grid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Column.Header.ToString() == "COLUMNNAME")
        {
            // e.Cancel = true;   // For not to include 
            // e.Column.IsReadOnly = true; // Makes the column as read only
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 8):

Each column has a `IsReadOnly` Property. Also, the whole DataGrid has the IsReadOnly as well [This does NOT affect the binding, just the ability of the user to edit the field]

EDIT:
Rushed an answer, sorry. I can only guess that you should NOT auto-generate columns if possible, so you can control which ones are readonly and which controltemplate goes where... just use the Binding property of the columns so you dont need to autogenerate them.

Comment: The AutoGenerateColumns is required since the query that creates the DataGrid is user-defined

Comment: I think this article might help you: http://blog.smoura.com/wpf-toolkit-datagrid-part-ii-custom-styling/ You will need to create your own style for that to happen tho, but i think its perfectly do-able

Comment: Nice article, but not really useful in my situation. I needed to set if a column was editable or not based on either its DisplayIndex or ColumnName, and I did not know in advance what my columns would be other than the single editable column.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void dgTableDetailAdj_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridColumn col in dgTableDetailAdj.Columns)
    {
        if (col.Header.Equals("columnName"))
        {
            col.IsReadOnly = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly (indent everything by at least 4 spaces, and don't indent more than is required). Also, code only answers are discouraged as they do not explain _how_ they solve the problem. Can you please [edit your post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37851029/edit) to resolve these issues? Thanks and welcome to StackOverflow.